# Embed a video from a password protected album using the Vimeo advanced API

Tags: api, passwords, embed, vimeo, protected

I have a Vimeo Plus account which allows me to add a password to an album of videos. I understand from the documentation that I need to use the advanced API to access password protected videos. I have been able to access a list of information about the videos in the album using the API method: vimeo.albums.getVideos.

However, I cannot see how to EMBED a video from the password protected album.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you send the url of the password protected video into Vimeo's OEmbed endpoint you should get the information you need.

You can find the documentation at https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed